# Go to next file after processing the file in the same folder using shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My files contains 5 files of 5 records

```
xaa --- filename
xab --- filename 
xac --- filename
xad --- filename
xae--- filename
```

5 records like below

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
```

Total 25 records - 5 in each file

Below is my part of the code which I am trying to achieve

For example

```
entry 1  ---processing
entry 2 ---processing
entry 3 ---completed
entry 4 --completed
entry 5 ---processing
```

If any of the entries got completed , I want to add remaining more entries for processing inside my shell script.

I want to pass another function to process jobs when  the count is less than 5 
I want to go to the next file in the same folder after reaching EOF when the count is less than 5 ,else the process is continues

```
if [[ $count -lt 5 ]]
        then 
            slot=5-$count
        echo "$slot are available"            
        echo "Having $slot to complete 5 entries processing"
    else

      echo "Process continues"     
fi
```

Ultimately,  I need to have 5 entries always being processed inside the shell until all the files are exhausted in the folder

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, please add some more details.